# How to change sever field's value on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have  have a small table in which when I click  add it appends new row, I have one column in my table i.e `Discount` which is for each row but outside the table I have a input field where I am giving discount and what I want is when I enter any discount that should be trigger to the corresponding input field, suppose I gave 10 discount then it should apply to each row to 10 in discount column

**My code**

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    discount: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        discount: 0,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    giveDiscount() {

      //here how I will asign the values in each discount row
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
    <input type="text">
    <button @click="giveDiscount">Discount</button>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="discount" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</script>
```

I have provided a input field with button initially discount is 0 to each row but I want to give them the value what I am typing in input field.

I just want to change that all rows field's of discount column

Comment: What shoud that discount do?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov the discount will be added to each row and the final amount corresponding to each row will be `amount-discount` or `sellingprice * quantity - discount = Amount`and the below Total Row's amount will also get updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need to reduce by discount your total value. But you haven't `bind` your discount input with any variable. Take a look at this:

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    discount: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice) - parseFloat(this.discount));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: [],
      discount: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        discount: +this.discount,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    giveDiscount() {
      this.tableDatas = this.tableDatas.map(item => {
        return {...item, discount: +this.discount}
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
    <input type="text" v-model="discount">
    <button @click="giveDiscount">Discount</button>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="discount" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</script>
```

Comment: hey the corresponding row amount is not re calculating, if quantity=1 and Selling price is 12 then amount=12 suppose then I am giving discount =2 then the corresponding amount of each row will be `10`  and no need to re calculate total row's amount because  that is amount before discount let it be as it is

Comment: @dheerajkumar check now